# Oracle database errors with vb.net

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, oracle, visual-studio-2012

I am tasked with making a simple GUI based database viewer. The database is hosted on our schools ftp server we must use visual basic and for the most part I've got it working I can search, view, and add to the database, but editing an existing record is giving me problems.

When I attempt to update the record I get a ora-00904 error invalid identifier when not using a colon (:) in where portion of the query and an ora-01008 not variables bound with a colon (:). We so far have only really used sqldeveloper and as a final project we were asked to use Visual Basic but we never covered anything like this in class so its a challenge I suppose.

PS: I only have that portion commented out so that I could view the error.

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
Dim strCustomerEmail As String = ""
Dim strLastName As String = ""
Dim strFirstName As String = ""
Dim strAddress As String = ""
Dim strCity As String = ""
Dim strState As String = ""
Dim intZip As Integer = 0
Dim datDateSignedUp As Date
Dim intCustomerNumber As Integer = 0


Try
    strCustomerEmail = CStr(txtCustomerEmail.Text)
    strLastName = CStr(txtLastName.Text)
    strFirstName = CStr(txtFirstName.Text)
    strAddress = CStr(txtAddress.Text)
    strCity = CStr(txtCity.Text)
    strState = CStr(txtState.Text)
    intZip = CInt(txtZip.Text)
    datDateSignedUp = CDate(txtDateSignedUp.Text)
    intCustomerNumber = CInt(txtCustomerNumber.Text)



    Dim sql As String = "UPDATE P_CLIENTS SET CUSTOMER_EMAIL = :CUSTOMER_EMAIL, LASTNAME = :LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME = :FIRSTNAME, ADDRESS = :ADDRESS, CITY = :CITY, STATE = :STATE, ZIP = :ZIP, DATE_SIGNED_UP = :DATE_SIGNED_UP, CUSTOMER# = :CUSTOMER# WHERE CUSTOMER_EMAIL = :EDIT_CUSTOMER_EMAIL"

    Dim cmd2 As New OracleCommand(sql, conn)
    conn.Open()
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("CUSTOMER_EMAIL", strCustomerEmail)
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("LASTNAME", strLastName)
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("FIRSTNAME", strFirstName)
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("ADDRESS", strAddress)
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("CITY", strCity)
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("STATE", strState)
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("ZIP", intZip)
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("DATE_SIGNED_UP", datDateSignedUp)
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("EDIT_CUSTOMER_EMAIL", strEditCustomerEmail)
    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()

    txtCustomerEmail.Text = strEditCustomerEmail
    txtLastName.Text = ""
    txtFirstName.Text = ""
    txtAddress.Text = ""
    txtCity.Text = ""
    txtState.Text = ""
    txtZip.Clear()
    txtDateSignedUp.Clear()
    txtCustomerNumber.Clear()
    'txtCustomerEmail.Select()

    txtCustomerEmail.Enabled = True
    txtLastName.Enabled = True
    txtFirstName.Enabled = True
    txtAddress.Enabled = True
    txtCity.Enabled = True
    txtState.Enabled = True
    txtZip.Enabled = True
    txtDateSignedUp.Enabled = True
    txtCustomerNumber.Enabled = True



    'Catch ex As Exception
    '    MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while attempting to add a new record.", "Error")
Finally
    conn.Close()
    txtCustomerEmail.Select()
End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you add the colon also in the parameters names when you add them to the parameters collection?

Comment: Are you missing Customer# from your parameters?

Comment: holy crap i think thats it....i'm missing customer# crap let me try that. ive been working on projects for days for my classes im so burned out im missing stuff like that.

Comment: hell yea that did it! thank you! solved!

Comment: How do I mark this as solved or answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `Customer#` from your parameter list.